# Как мне изменить переменную на какое-то время?

Tags: c#

У меня есть переменная: `int TemporaryMode = 0;`
Я хочу запустить метод, который изменит `TemporaryMode` на 1, а через 15 секунд поменяет обратно на 0. Как мне это сделать?

Я попробовал таймер использовать, но там, как мне кажется, только тики ненужные есть.

код с таймером:

```cs
TemporaryModeTimer = new Timer(duration.Value.TotalMilliseconds);
TemporaryModeTimer.Start();
TemporaryModeTimer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
{
    TemporaryMode = value switch
    {
         0 => LogicalStateType.Off,
         1 => LogicalStateType.On
    };
    Console.WriteLine(TemporaryMode);
}
```

Comment: Таймер или поток.

Comment: я пытался использовать таймер, но он вызывается раз в n секунд, а это не совсем то, что мне нужно

Comment: _только тики ненужные есть_ - ничего не понял. Какой тип приложения и какой именно таймер из какого пространства имён используете?

Comment: не совсем понятно, как мне правильно реализовать логику с таймером

Comment: @aepot обычное консольное приложение, using System.Timers;

Comment: Вызовите внутри Elapsed TemporaryModeTimer.Stop()

Comment: *"я пытался использовать таймер, но он вызывается раз в n секунд"* - а вам нужно 15сек, в чем проблема? )

Comment: мне нужно не каждые 15 секунд, а что-то из рубрики "держи значение переменной в течение 15 сек"

Comment: уже ответ выше дал в комментарии, не вижу проблемы попробовать

Comment: А зачем тут таймер я не пойму? Сделали `Task`, который будет в себе содержать, например `TemporaryMode = 1; await Task.Delay(15000); TemporaryMode = 0;`, дальше запустили эту задачу без ожидания и готово, будет переключение через время. Если нужна еще и отмена, то добавляем `CancellationToken` и ловим исключение отмены, готово.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ точно! так и сделал, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вы правильно думаете.
Добавляем Timer

//-----------------------------

```
public static class Program 
{
   private static LogicalStateType TemporaryMode = LogicalStateType.Off;
   private static System.Timers.Timer _timer = null;

   public static void Main() 
   {
       _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
       _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
       _timer.Interval = 15000; // 15 sec
       _timer.Enabled = false;
       ....
       TemporaryMode = LogicalStateType.On;
       _timer.Enabled = true;
       ....
   }
   private static void TimerCallback(Object o) 
   {
       _timer.Enabled = false;
       TemporaryMode = LogicalStateType.Off;
   }
}
```

Comment: У вас winforms Timer, другой

Comment: Я ответ написал, когда кода небыло :) Но суть ясна

Answer (score 0):

У вас в комментариях один товарищ уже ответил на этот вопрос, здесь не обязательно нужен таймер. Можно создать Task с ожиданием в 15 секунд.

```
// Для того чтобы приложение не повисло из-за ожидания задачи - 
// объявляем лямда-выражение асинхронным.
var switchTemporaryState = new Task(async () => 
{
    TemporaryMode = LogicalStateType.On;
    await Task.Delay(15000); // 15000 ms delay
    TemporaryMode = LogicalStateType.Off;
});

// Вызов таска.
switchTemporaryState.Start();
```

Не совсем понятно за что отвечает TemporaryMode, если вам не подходит этот фрагмент, пожалуйста, опишите подробнее какую задачу вам нужно решить.